# Average occupancy and and its variance

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, average, variance, balls-in-bins

I have $N$ boxes with a given number of balls among the boxes. I know the occupancy distribution so I have the average number of balls per bins (let's call it the mean).

The underlying process is that at every time step we can add or remove a balls from one bins according to a given rule.

So during the process the average occupancy fluctuates (i.e. the mean has a variance and a distribution)

Is that possible to determine **a connection between the the variance of the mean and the variance of the original occupancy distribution?**

Comment: What does "add or remove a balls from one bins according to a given rule" mean?

Comment: I have a process of add an remove balls from bins, but this process a stationary distribution which has an average value ( mean occupancy) and a variance. Now also the mean occupancy fluctuates, is there a way to relate it to the the stationary distribution?